# Listen to AJAX complete event from a behavior

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have a form that has an AJAX button.  When I click it, it updates a bunch of stuff as expected which is fine.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a listener in behavior that gets called when the AJAX call is complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is :

```
Drupal.behaviors.YourBehaviour = {
attach: function(context, settings) {  
  $('#yourform').ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if ($(event.target.id) == 'the-id-of-your-item') {
      // Your code here
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: +1, but for Drupal 7 it would be `Drupal.behaviors.YourBehaviour = { attach: function() { $('#yourform').ajaxComplete...`

Comment: You're right : forgot a line while pasting !

Comment: you don't need this $() just event.target.id you are't referencing an object

Comment: Why wrap it in Drupal behaviours?

Comment: Because it's considered best practice and prevents namespaces collisions, among other things.

Answer (score 15):

For versions of jQuery 1.8+, it seems you now must attach the .ajaxComplete function to the document, not the form or the view itself (see http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

The following worked for me on D7 with Jquery 1.10 and Views 7.x-3.8, where "your_view_id" is the machine name of the view set in the view's "Other" settings panel. There is a lot of other info in event, xhr and settings to key off of to determine if the ajax result is for the view you want, but this worked for my situation:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if(typeof settings.extraData != 'undefined' && typeof settings.extraData.view_display_id != 'undefined') {

        switch(settings.extraData.view_display_id){

            case "your_view_id":

                console.log('your_view_id ajax results!');

                break;

            default:

                console.log('some other ajax result...');

                break;

        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

**None** of the given solutions worked for me with *Drupal 7.24, jQuery 1.11* and *Views 7.x-3.8*.

What *user1193694* suggested was not bad, but the settings object that I received didn't have the *extraData* parameter.

When parsing the settings object i saw that the settings.data propertiy contains '*view_name=*' and your view's machine name, so thats what i am filtering for:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {

    // see if it is from our view
    if (settings.data.indexOf( "view_name=your_views_name") != -1) {

            console.log('your_view_id ajax results!');

    }
});
```

Replace '*your_views_name*' with the machine name of your view.