# How to add behavior-based onclick to ajax-enabled Form API button?

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have a form with a button:

```
$form['categories_update'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Load category-related properties'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_mymodule_categories_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'categories_properties',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'prevent' => 'submit',
  ),
  '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);
```

Now, in Behavior I'm using:

```
(function($) { 
  var initialised = false;

  Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleTag = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Unrelated code

      $('#edit-categories-update', context).on('click', function(){
        console.log('Load category-related prperties clicked');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

And it simply fails to work - no errors in console, but no code executed either.

It works all right when I comment out `'#ajax'` part of a button's definition. Is there a way to have both behavior JS and Form API Ajax working for one button?

I'm using jQuery update module in it's dev version, and I have it set to jQuery 1.8. The button is not inside the wrapper, so it's ID is not affected by AJAX call (verified in browser).

Comment: It was easy to find how to make one of the 2 work, a lot of advices, but nothing how to make them work *together* :/

Comment: @Beebee Question updated - yes, I have checked these. Sorry for missing it in my post.

Comment: What were you thinking of doing within the custom click handler? Is it something that can be achieved using one of the [ajax commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7)?

Comment: @Beebee I wanted to reset global JS variable `initialised` to `FALSE` and re-run my own initialisation function just the way it was executed on the page load. I never get used to using ajax commands.

Comment: Could `.ajaxComplete()` work for your case then? There's a solution posted [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/listen-to-ajax-complete-event-from-a-behavior)

Comment: @Beebee actually yes, putting `$('#edit-categories-update').ajaxSuccess(function() {` in place of ` $('#edit-categories-update', context).on('click', function(){` did it. That's the answer, it seems.

Comment: Great, feel free to post your own answer. I'll skip since I only found a dup (which wasn't exactly your solution either).

Comment: @Beebee done, answer posted. Of course feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by creating a function in the js file and then calling the function using the Drupal ajax_command_invoke() function.

For example, in the js put this:

```
$.fn.yourmodule_somename = function() {
  console.log('Load category-related prperties clicked');
}
```

And then in the AJAX callback, put this to call that function:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'yourmodule_somename');
```

Answer (score 1):

Form API `#ajax` effectively disables behaviors on elements. I can't see this documented, but that's how it works, consistently. So the solution was to change the line:

```
$('#edit-categories-update', context).on('click', function(){
```

and make it

```
$('#edit-categories-update').ajaxSuccess(function() {
```

That way code was not executed on click, but after processing of AJAX triggered by the button succeeded. It's not useful if you want to perform JavaScript *before* AJAX call, but if you need it to happen *after*, or if you *don't care*, it is a sufficient solution. If you need things to happen before AJAX call, use this instead:

```
$('#edit-categories-update').ajaxStart(function() {
```